# iTunes can't sync contacts as contacts has been disabled on iPhone

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, contacts

I am getting this error message.

```
itunes can't sync contacts as contacts has been disabled on iphone
```

Configuration: iOS 6.1, iphone 4

Answer (score 1):

1. back up address book  [File>Export]
2. delete all contacts in address book
3. delete all files within: library>user>application support>address book
4. untick "sync contacts" in iTunes - click on "Sync" button
5. open address book: import file (the backup file)
6. open iTunes: tick "sync contacts" - click on "Sync" button

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [restoring the device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) through iTunes? It appears this [was an issue](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2800) with older devices back in iOS 3 days and a restore would resolve the issue.